# Android - Control an activity from member class

Tags: android, android-activity, gesture, gesturedetector

First, I'm quite beginner to Android programming, I got some basis in Java and I looked on SO and googled my problem with no match.
I've been trying to make the following [tutorial](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/The_Widget_Pack_Part_3_Swipe/) work for several hours. The project is composed of two classes : an activity and a class SwipeDetector which extends `SimpleOnGestureListener`.

The solution offered by Motorola website works but I got trouble when I tried to "modify" the activity when left or right swipe is detected. To test it, I expected some Toasts to show when swiping.

My "solution" was to create a constructor for SwipeDetector which takes as parameters the `ActivityClass` and `Context` of calling `Activity`. When these informations are known it's easye to call `mParent.moveScreenRight();` where mParent is the parent Activity.

I'm aware that this solution seems awful, and I hope I could get some advices here. I can provide more information about the two classes impletentations if needed.

Thanks !

Regards,
Jerome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your description exactly what the problem is, but reading between the lines and looking at the tutorial, I think what you're missing is that the SwipeDetector in the tutorial is an inner class of the Activity. That's the only way it could call `moveScreenRight()` or `moveSreenLeft()`, which call the `mFlipper` member of the Activity class.

So the code should look something like

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  // All the Activity overrides elided

  class SwipeDetector extends SimpleGestureListener {

    // all the SwipeDetector methods
  }
}
```

Short of making SwipeDetector an inner class, there's really no avoiding passing a reference to its constructor to enable calling methods on the Activity. The cleanest way to abstract that away is with the interface solution suggested by Joseph Earl.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll try your solution soon. It seems the tutorial writer thought reader would implement it this way. I must admit I don't really like this presentation of classes inside other ones but it seems it's sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your Gesture detector take an interface so you can pass in different activities.

```
interface MovableActivity {

    public void moveLeft();
    public void moveRight();
}
```

Then in your actual activity `implement` MovableActivity

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements MovableActivity { ...
```

Then your constructor for the swipe detector can take a `MovableActivity` and call `moveLeft` and `moveRight` on that.

Comment: Thx Joseph !
During my quest, I figured interface might help since I could not extend two classes but I had no clue how to do it... I'll try and report back here !